# Use the Get Method to extract only certains parts of an index in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list that is made up of different types. I want to use the get method in the array list to extract only one element from a specified index

```
public BookCollection() {
    collection = new ArrayList<Book>(10);
}

public void addbook(String title, String author, int year, double cost, boolean Available) {
    Book a = new Book(title, director, year, cost, Available);
    collection.add(a);
}
```

In the above code I want to create a library of books but then at some point I only want the title.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BookCollection library = new BookCollection();
    library.addbook("Pride & Prejudice", "Jane Austen", 1801, 24.95, true);
    System.out.println(collection.get(0).toString())
}
```

Then I want to get just the title. So in this case it would be Pride & Prejudice. At the moment the out output is "Pride & PrejudiceJane Austen180124.95"
But I want it to be just "Pride & Prejudice".

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should consider providing a more clear example and refactoring the question!

Answer (score 2):

```
collection.get(0).getTitle()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Gygabyte's answer is right. You should create getter methods in your Book class for every field, so you can call separately whenever you want.

You should also check Java rules and conventions, in this particular case, variable and method names should start with a lowercase letter, so you should switch from "Available" to "available".

Uppercase letters are for Classes.

I tried your code and found a solution, hope it will be right for you:

This is BookCollection class:

```
public class BookCollection extends ArrayList<Book>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<Book> collection;

public BookCollection() {
    this.collection = new ArrayList<Book>();
}

public void addbook(String title, String author, int year, double cost, boolean available) {
    Book a = new Book(title, author, year, cost, available);
    this.add(a);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    BookCollection library = new BookCollection();
    library.addbook("Pride & Prejudice", "Jane Austen", 1801, 24.95, true);
    System.out.println(library.get(0).isAvailable());
}
}
```

And this is Book class, with getters and setters:

```
public class Book {

private String name;
private String author;
private int year;
private double cost;
private boolean available;

public Book(String name, String author, int year, double cost, boolean available){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.available = available;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public double getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public boolean isAvailable() {
    return available;
}

public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
    this.available = available;
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I created a getter method as you suggested (as well as creating the this.title variable in the addbook method) and tried to use it within my driver like so "System.out.println(movies.get(0).gettitle());"
But I got the error message "The method get(int) is undefined for the type BookCollection"

Comment: Didn't you have this error before applying my changes? What is "movies"? Can you post more code?

Comment: Before applying your changes, it was just printing the entirety of what was at the index. e.g. "Pride & PrejudiceJane Austen180124.95"
"movies" is a typo. I meant to write "library" in that position

Comment: I've posted all of the code I have used so far. I am adapting it from some code I have previously written that stores an array list of movies. I wanted to see if I could make something more specific

Comment: ok, so just add the method getTitle in the Book Class, then try System.out.println(collection.get(0).getTitle());

Comment: It comes up with "The method get(int) is undefined for the type BookCollection"